# Finding sum of list in prolog shows factors of sum, not final sum result

Tags: prolog

I am trying to find the sum of a list in Prolog. Below is the total/sum code. It's close to working, however it returns the factors of the sum instead of just the sum. New to Prolog so I am not sure why this is happening.

```
sum([], 0).
sum([X|Tail],Sum):-
   sum(Tail,Temp),
   Sum=Temp+X.
```

Why does this result in the factors of the total being shown instead of the actual total value? The values add up to the correct answer, just not sure why it is displayed like this.
Input/Output:

```
Total = 0+3000.0+1900.0+1312.5+3000+1900+5000 ?
```

Comment: Say `Total is Temp+X`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using *term unification* (`=/2`) instead of *arithmetic evaluation* (`is/2`) in the `totalList/2` predicate:

```
totalList([], 0).
totalList([X|Tail],Total):-
    totalList(Tail,Temp),
    Total=Temp+X.
```

Rewrite as:

```
total_list([], 0).
total_list([X| Tail], Total):-
    total_list(Tail, Temp),
    Total is Temp + X.
```

The rename from `totalList` to `total_list` follows Prolog coding guidelines for predicate names.

Although not a bug, the performance of your predicate also suffers from not being *tail-recursive*. I.e. the recursive call in the second clauses is not the last goal in its body. Therefore, it will consume space proportional to the number of elements in the list. You can fix this problem by using an *accumulator*:

```
total_list(List, Sum) :-
    total_list(List, 0, Sum).

total_list([], Sum, Sum).
total_list([X| Tail], Sum0, Sum):-
    Sum1 is Sum0 + X,
    total_list(Tail, Sum1, Sum).
```

This improved definition will run in constant space in most Prolog systems.